# Iterate Each Cell Of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to iterate each cell of my DataGridView and if the value = 0 or 0.00 I want to change it to a - I have the below code, but I am getting an error of

> Possible unintended reference comparison

What would be the proper way to achieve what I am after here?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in rw.Cells)
    {
       if (rw.Cells[0].Value == "0")
       {
          rw.Cells[0].Value = "-";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting error at runtime or compile time ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya compile time

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: if (rw.Cells[0].Value == "0")

Comment: You are looking thru all the cells of the row but compare and change value of only Cells[0]. Anyways what you need to do is `if(rw.Cells[0].Value.ToString()=="")`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - the line of code is never hit to alter a 0 to a -

Comment: Sorry I meant `if(rw.Cells[0].Value.ToString()=="0")`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - that causes the value to change, but I get an error of - is not a valid value for decimal?  The datasource for my datagridview1 = datatableSQLPull

Comment: What is `datatableSQLPull`? If the columns of datagridview are auto generated then you can not change the value of cell to other data type.

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  It appears that your goal is to format zero values to display as "-".  The solution to this should not involve changing the underlying value, but rather the displayed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2), `DataGridViewCell.Value` returns an `object`. Now you'd like to compare this with your `string` "0".
When trying to compare `object` and `string`, you will compare their *references*, but not their *values*. Basically you're just checking whether they point to the same object.
If your cell ALWAYS contains objects of type `string`, you could simply do the following:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in rw.Cells)
    {
        var currentValue = (string)rw.Cells[0].Value;
        if (currentValue == "0")
        {
            currentValue = "-";
        }
    }
}
```

A more safe approach:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in rw.Cells)
    {
        var currentValue = rw.Cells[0].Value as string;
        if (currentValue != null && currentValue == "0")
        {
            currentValue = "-";
        }
    }
}
```